# How to assign sequential hotkeys in autohotkey? ctrl+K followed by ctrl+D

Tags: autohotkey

I want to run a function when these key sequences are pressed:

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> followed by <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>

when doing the above, we hold down ctrl throughout the whole process.
I want to assign function1() to <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>, but assign function2() to this combination: <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> followed by <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>

Is it achievable in autohotkey to do so?

Only to make things clear, you can think of that combination in Visual Studio which is used to format the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I edited and made an adjustment to the second code provided by user3419297, here it is:

```
;~ If you want to wait for only one second after ctrl+K,

^k::
    ctrl_k_var := true
    sleep 1000  ; wait 1 second for ctrl+D
    if (ctrl_k_var)  ; If  you don't press ctrl+D within 1 second after ctrl+K
        MsgBox, ctrl+K
    ctrl_k_var := false
return

#If ctrl_k_var

    ^d::    
        MsgBox, ctrl+K+D
        ctrl_k_var := false
    return

#If
```

This script will not bind <kbd>Ctrl+D</kbd> at all times, it will only use <kbd>Ctrl+D</kbd> only when <kbd>Ctrl+K</kbd> is pressed, and only then it will wait for <kbd>Ctrl+D</kbd> for only 1 second. The downside with the answer given by user3419297 was that his script would bind <kbd>Ctrl+D</kbd> with autohotkey at all the times that the script was running, I adusted the code so that it will only get <kbd>Ctrl+D</kbd> only after <kbd>Ctrl+K</kbd> is pressed. So <kbd>Ctrl+D</kbd> is not bound at all times with autohotkey, therefore other programs also can use <kbd>Ctrl+D</kbd> when <kbd>Ctrl+K</kbd> is not pressed by the user.

Answer (score 1):

```
^k::
ctrl_k_var := true           ; assign the Boolean value "true" or "1" to this variable
SetTimer ctrl_k_action, -50  ; launch the "ctrl_k_action" subroutine automatically after this hotkey
return

^d::
; KeyWait, Ctrl             ; wait for Ctrl to be released
If (ctrl_k_var)             ; If the variable "ctrl_k_var" has the value "true" 
{
    ; SendRaw ctrl+K+D
    MsgBox, ctrl+K+D
    ctrl_k_var := false
}
else
{
    ; SendRaw ctrl+D
    MsgBox, ctrl+D
}
return


ctrl_k_action:
    KeyWait, Ctrl
    If (ctrl_k_var)
    {
        ; SendRaw ctrl+K
        MsgBox, ctrl+K
    }
    ctrl_k_var := false
return
```

EDIT:
It waits for ctrl+D after getting ctrl+K as long as you're holding down the Ctrl key. If you want to wait for only one second after ctrl+K, try this:

```
^k::
    ctrl_k_var := true
    sleep 1000  ; wait 1 second for ctrl+D
    if (ctrl_k_var)  ; If  you don't press ctrl+D within 1 second after ctrl+K
        MsgBox, ctrl+K
    ctrl_k_var := false
return

^d::
    if (ctrl_k_var)  ; If  you press ctrl+D within 1 second after ctrl+K
        MsgBox, ctrl+K+D
    else
        MsgBox, ctrl+D
    ctrl_k_var := false
return
```

**EDIT 2:** I edited the first code so that it waits only in the first function (ctrl+K) for Ctrl to be released.

Comment: Your script has a flaw, it waits indefinitely for ctrl+D after getting ctrl+K

Comment: How can we ajust it so that it only waits for 1 second for ctrl+D after getting Ctrl+K?

Comment: It waits for ctrl+D after getting ctrl+K as long as you're holding down the Ctrl key. If you want to wait for only one second, try my edited answer.